# Configure instance profile for EC2 instances to attach/detach/wait for EBS volumes and work with S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-ebs

I'd like to have instances attach EBS volumes in their init script (passed via UserData).

I've installed awscli on EC2 instance, but it misses credentials.

How can I allow my instances to attach volumes (and work with S3) without copying my credentials there?

From what I understand, I need to add policies to IAM role / instance profile. I found this tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_ebs-owner.html but I don't understand what is `Condition` and if it's mandatory.

To simplify I'd like to allow my instances working with all my EBS drives and S3. (If it's possible to limit the work only to EBS drives / S3 buckets with names starting with some prefix, that would be even better)

How do I create such an Instance Profile with boto3 so that credentials are not needed for awscli?

Thanks!

**UPD:** I tried the following code to create an instance profile and got the following error when executing `aws ec2 attach-volume` on an instance launched with the created instance profile. What am I missing?

```py
name = 'myname'
trust_relationship_policy_document = dict(
    Version = '2012-10-17',
    Statement = dict(
        Effect = 'Allow',
        Principal = dict(Service = 'ec2.amazonaws.com'),
        Action = 'sts:AssumeRole'
    )
)

policy_document = dict(
    Version = '2012-10-17',
    Statement = [dict(
        Effect = 'Allow',
        Action = [
            'ec2:AttachVolume',
            'ec2:DetachVolume'
        ],
        Resource = 'arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*',
    )]
)

iam.create_role(RoleName = name, AssumeRolePolicyDocument = json.dumps(trust_relationship_policy_document))
policy_arn = iam.create_policy(PolicyName = name, PolicyDocument = json.dumps(policy_document))['Policy']['Arn']
iam.attach_role_policy(RoleName = name, PolicyArn = policy_arn)
iam.create_instance_profile(InstanceProfileName = name)
iam.add_role_to_instance_profile(InstanceProfileName = name, RoleName = name)

# An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the AttachVolume operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message:
```

Comment: Launch the EC2 instance with an IAM role that has the relevant IAM permissions. You can also attach an IAM role to a running instance.

Comment: @jarmod how long has that been a thing? for years you could modify an existing instance profile, but adding an instance profile to and instance that didn't have one used to not be supported

Comment: @jordanm you can [attach](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#attach-iam-role) an IAM role to an instance that's running or stopped. Not sure when this was first introduced but a quick browse of wayback machine suggests it's been available since early 2017, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Before launching the Amazon EC2 instance, **create an IAM Role** with the necessary permissions. You can leave out the Condition if you want to permit *any* EBS Volume to be attached.

Then, launch the Amazon EC2 instance with that IAM Role associated to the instance. This will automatically provide credentials to the AWS CLI and any other software on the instance that wants to access your AWS services.

Your script can then call `aws ec2 attach-volume`, etc.